# Visualization for absolute continuity

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I can't get the intuition behind the definition. I would like to see where a function could fail to be absolute continuous, when it's obv that it is one of those etc...
I really appraciate any kind of help.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Examples

Comment: It's really difficult for me with few examples

Comment: You can read this exposition and see if it makes sense. https://www.quora.com/What-is-an-example-of-a-function-which-is-uniformly-continuous-but-not-absolutely-continuous/answer/Alon-Amit?ch=10&share=d44ca173&srid=LZ5x